# How do I calculate the best, average, and worst case probability of an event that has varying probability based on four other varying probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

```
A group of people have 100,000 beans, with an indeterminate amount of beans per person.

If someone gives me 4 beans, I give them back $1. 

If someone gives me 3 beans, there is an X% chance I give them back $1.

If someone gives me 2 beans, there is a Y% chance I give them back $1.

If someone gives me 1 bean, there is a Z% chance I give them back $1.

The 4-bean chance is 100% and X > Y > Z.
```

They can repeat this as many times as they want but once they give me the beans I do not give them back, meaning the two opposite extremes would be I give away `$25,000` in total to people who all give me exactly `4` beans or I give away `$100,000` in total to people who all give me exactly 1 bean and got very lucky.

How do I calculate and/or visualize the chances that I give out over `$50000` given a random sample of bean amounts given to me? How do I calculate/visualize this given a *specified*  amount of beans given to me for certain #s of beans$^1$?

How do I calculate/visualize the probability that I give out $75,000?

$^1$If I know that `10,000` people will give me exactly `4` beans, how do I calculate the odds for the remaining `60,000` beans? Assuming the chances of people giving `3` beans, `2` beans, and `1` bean are equal.

I understand there is some permutation/combinatorial probability and game theory involved, but I don't really even know where to start in terms of thinking about and framing a formula for the problem.

Comment: Why would anyone consider any of the other options outside of 4 and 1 beans. 1 bean gives me the highest probability, outside of certainty, and the cost is only 1 bean for the same return as if I am to give away 2 beans. Are you sure the direction is not reversed $X>Y>Z$? That is higher probability for more beans given.

Comment: @NoeVidales That was a typo, sorry. Yes, it's a descending probability from highest to lowest number of beans.

Comment: Do the beans have to exhausted or can some of the beans be retained when considering the different dollar amounts? That is can I achieve $50,000 with just 50,000 beans.

Comment: @NoeVidales Assume that over time eventually everyone will turn in their beans to me. For the sake of the problem and my issue, I need to calculate how likely it is I have to give out more than some set amount of $ and prepare for it